# Kamailio and rtpproxy error and why do we need rtpproxy (example that works without it)

Tags: kamailio

I am using Kamailio version 5.0.3 (x86_64/linux), and it is installed and working on a Centos 7 Sever.  I use Kamailio as a SIP Proxy Server for Asterisk and things seem to work fine, however, I do have an issue and a question for which I am trying to understand and am hoping someone can help me with.

For the sake of the argument, my server name is myServer, and it’s IP Address is 172.1.1.13; Asterisk is on a different server.

Issue:  Every 10 seconds I get an Error message in the Kamailio log which says => 
Nov 13 18:10:55 myServer /usr/local/sbin/kamailio[29188]: ERROR:  [core/tcp_main.c:2660]: tcpconn_1st_send(): connect 172.1.1.13:59794 failed (RST) Connection refused.

I do not know what triggers this error, and as mentioned, things do seem to work; I can make calls and use sip tools which pass requests through the Kamailio to Asterisk.  Does anyone know what could be causing this Error?  I do not understand what is trying to connect to what at such a high port.

Question: The way I understand it, rtpproxy is needed to pass video/audio through Kamailio to Asterisk.  However, even without rtpproxy running, I get video through to Asterisk and the video plays with no issues on a sip device (e.g. MicroSIP).  I am confused what I need rtpproxy for. 
Note: Even with no rtpproxy, I get the same error mentioned above in the Issue section.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

- This seems like you have mentioned this connection port for some service within `kamailio.cfg` , so you should look into your `kamailio.cfg` and see why is it connection to **172.1.1.13:59794** and you'll know to why it's trying to connect .
- `RTPProxy` or `RtpEngine` is used for the `Relaying` purposes and it can also do the `crypto` things between legacy `SIP client` and `webRTC clients`, however the latest module can also record the calls as `.pcap` or `.mp3/.wav`